# How do I open a specific .aspx page from Visual Studios in browser

Tags: asp.net

When I compile, I want the browser to go to that page instead of going to the log in page, when I set it as Startup page, VS starts not responding and freezes the screen. This is a very simple question but I cannot find the answer to it.

Answer (score 0):

For an .aspx page, many possible reasons could cause "VS starts not responding and freezes the screen". I would suggest that you check your aspx file and the code behind file to see if there is any database connection and it loads large amount of data. Any pre-initiate program error could also bring page load failure. You may try move your GUI code to a separate html file and then view it in a browser to see what happens.